# App icon and name missing in android even when manifest has a main activity

Tags: android

I cannot see app icon and app name on my app on my phone/emulator. I can only start it using run button inside android studio. So when i close the app on my phone there is i cannot find i icon shortcut. The app is however shown under setting and i can uninstall it from there.

my manifest has

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_card_giftcard_black_24dp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.mindedges.easyquiz.easyquiz.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Why am i not seeing a shortcut for app?There is no way by which i can start the app once i close it.

Comment: Add android:icon in application tag

Comment: Remove the `<data>` element from that `<intent-filter>`. If you want `LoginActivity` to handle an `Intent` for that, create a separate `<intent-filter>` for it, with the relevant `<action>` and `<category>` elements.

Comment: tried both of it, no luck

Comment: Did you try cleaning/rebuilding, and uninstalling/reinstalling after making those changes?

Comment: are you sure you cannot find the application anywhere? Coz it seem like you dont have problem with your code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your Icon tags:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

in you `application` tag.

Comment: I can see it now.